# Getting a 404 when calling Authentication API using auth0.net

Tags: c#, authentication, auth0

I am trying to authenticate using [auth0.net](https://github.com/auth0/auth0.net) (.NET client for the Auth0 API), however, I'm getting an `Auth0.Core.Exceptions.ApiException` error with an HTTP status code of `NotFound (404)`.

I'm using the following code:

```
var client = new AuthenticationApiClient(new Uri(Auth0Url));

var authenticationRequest = new AuthenticationRequest();
authenticationRequest.ClientId = ClientId;
authenticationRequest.Username = username;
authenticationRequest.Password = password;
authenticationRequest.Connection = "Username-Password-Authentication";

AuthenticationResponse response = null;
Task.Run(async () =>
{
    response = await client.AuthenticateAsync(authenticationRequest);
}).Wait();
```

What is wrong here? The Management API works fine and the `ClientID` is correct.

Comment: What are the contents of the `Auth0Url` variable? You can omit/change the tenant name part in the domain if you don't want to disclose that.

Comment: @João , it is very good question! Shame on me! It should be not the same as one used for Management API.

Answer (score 1):

Just had this problem myself.

Two things.

**First** make sure you are using the correct API Url.

E.g.

`https://<company>.au.auth0.com/api/v2`

And not
`https://<company>.au.auth0.com`

**Second** Make sure you are using the base API

E.g.

`https://<company>.au.auth0.com/api/v2`

And not
`https://<company>.au.auth0.com/api/v2/users`